# Nodejs send metrics of how many people are using my app

Tags: node.js, metrics

So i'm designing a new application with Nodejs and packaging into an executable then putting a release in github, I want to be able to monitor how many people are using my executable?

I was thinking about creating an api server and my application just make a call to that API service but I thought there might be something already out there any help?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to connect third party services that do that. The most famous one is [Google Analytics](https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/analytics/)

You just need to create your developer account and embed a few lines of tracking code. After that you can see full info about your visitors including their location.

Comment: not sure if GA fits to the question since the question is about server side actually

Comment: I have actually tried google analytics but need to send data on start up of the application about the version of the app their using